# reboot VM trigger a reboot of the mother server

Tags: server, crash, kvm, reboot

Reboot VM trigger an immediate reboot of the master system.

the same symptom whether I do it with the reboot command using SSH or Button in VMM or using the virsh command in the main virtualization server.

The reboot is very fast. It looks like a main system crash.